# How to implement the operator in with ANTLR

Tags: antlr4

I'm developing a DSL with ANTLR and I want to implement the in operator, here my syntax

```
x = 3
where x in 2,3,4
```

here is part of my grammar.

```
expr    : ID       GT   DATA NEWLINE
        | ID       LT   DATA NEWLINE
        | ID       GTEQ DATA NEWLINE
        | ID       LTEQ DATA NEWLINE
        | ID       IN   LIST NEWLINE
        ;
GT      : '>';  
LT      : '<';  
GTEQ    : '>=';  
LTEQ    : '<=';
IN      : 'in';
LIST    : DATA ',' DATA (',' DATA)* ; // list of variables
DATA    : '"' ID '"' | '"' INT '"';
ID  :   [a-zA-Z]+ ; 
INT :   [0-9]+ ;
```

How I can get the list of variables in the entryExpr method ,in our example list = [2,3,4 ]

```
@Override public void enterExpr(StudyParser.ExprContext ctx) { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've implemented it now, `2,3,4` is a single token. This is not what you want. It should really be a parser rule:

```
list : DATA ',' DATA (',' DATA)*;
```

You probably want your comparison operators to have the same precedence, so you could wrap them in a single alt:

```
expr : ID (GT | LT | GTEQ | LTEQ) DATA NEWLINE  #exprComp
     | ID IN list NEWLINE                       #exprIn
     ;
```

And the [`#...` labels at the end](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#alternative-labels) of the rules will cause the `void enterExpr(StudyParser.ExprContext ctx)` to be replaced by the following 2 methods:

```java
void enterExprComp(StudyParser.ExprCompContext ctx);

void enterExprIn(StudyParser.ExprInContext ctx);
```

In your implementation of `enterExprIn` you can now do:

```java
@Override 
public void enterExprIn(StudyParser.ExprInContext ctx) {
  for (TerminalNode node : ctx.list().DATA()) {
    System.out.println(node.getText());
  }
}
```